# copy object from a subview then place object

Tags: arrays, swift, append, clone, subview

I want my swift code to copy the object which is a brown view. So the user hits the copy button then the user hits the object they want to copy and then they point to the area where they want to place the object. Basically the gif below is exactly what I am look at I don't know if you would do something like a clone of something like this.

[image]

```
import UIKit;import CoreData

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    var addBoxes = [UIImageView]()
    let subview = UIImageView()
    var currentView: UIView?
    
    var box = UIButton()
    
    var copyButton = UIButton()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        [box,copyButton].forEach {
            $0.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            view.addSubview($0)
        }
        
        box.backgroundColor = .red
        
        box.setTitle("Add", for: .normal)
        
        copyButton.setTitle("Copy", for: .normal)
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        
        box.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: copyButton.trailingAnchor),
        box.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor),
        box.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.heightAnchor, multiplier: 0.04),
        box.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo:view.widthAnchor ,multiplier: 0.5),
        
        copyButton.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor),
        copyButton.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor),
        copyButton.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.heightAnchor, multiplier: 0.04),
        copyButton.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo:view.widthAnchor ,multiplier: 0.5),
        
        
        ])
        
        copy.addTarget(self, action: #selector(copyBox), for: .touchDown)
        box.addTarget(self, action: #selector(addQuarter), for: .touchDown)
        
        
        copyButton.backgroundColor = .blue
        
    }

    override var prefersStatusBarHidden: Bool {
        return true
    }
    
    @objc func copyBox() {
        
    }
    
    @objc func handlePanGestured(_ gesture: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
        currentView = gesture.view
        
        let draggedView = gesture.view!
        view.bringSubviewToFront(draggedView)
        
        let translation = gesture.translation(in: view)
        draggedView.center = CGPoint(x: draggedView.center.x + translation.x, y: draggedView.center.y + translation.y)
        gesture.setTranslation(.zero, in: view)
    }

    @objc func addQuarter(){
        
        let subview = UIImageView()
        
        subview.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        addBoxes.append(subview)
        view.addSubview(subview)
        
        let pan = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handlePanGestured(_:)))
        
        subview.addGestureRecognizer(pan)
     
        subview.frame = CGRect(x: view.bounds.midX , y: view.bounds.midY + CGFloat(100), width: CGFloat(100), height: 100)
        subview.backgroundColor = .brown
        
        addBoxes.append(subview)
        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Achieve your requirement with code

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

var addBoxes = [UIImageView]()
let subview = UIImageView()
var currentView: UIView?
var location: CGPoint = CGPoint.zero

var box = UIButton()

var copyButton = UIButton()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    [box,copyButton].forEach {
        $0.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.addSubview($0)
    }
    
    box.backgroundColor = .red
    
    box.setTitle("Add", for: .normal)
    
    copyButton.setTitle("Copy", for: .normal)
    
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
    
    box.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: copyButton.trailingAnchor),
    box.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor),
    box.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.heightAnchor, multiplier: 0.04),
    box.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo:view.widthAnchor ,multiplier: 0.5),
    
    copyButton.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor),
    copyButton.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor),
    copyButton.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.heightAnchor, multiplier: 0.04),
    copyButton.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo:view.widthAnchor ,multiplier: 0.5),
    
    
    ])
    
    copyButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(copyBox), for: .touchDown)
    box.addTarget(self, action: #selector(addQuarter), for: .touchDown)
    
    
    copyButton.backgroundColor = .blue
    
    self.view.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleTapGestured(_:))))
    
}

override var prefersStatusBarHidden: Bool {
    return true
}

@objc func copyBox() {
    if let copyObject = currentView?.copyView as? UIImageView{
        copyObject.center = location
        copyObject.addGestureRecognizer(UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handlePanGestured(_:))))
        view.addSubview(copyObject)
    }
}

@objc func handlePanGestured(_ gesture: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
    currentView = gesture.view
    
    let draggedView = gesture.view!
    view.bringSubviewToFront(draggedView)
    
    let translation = gesture.translation(in: view)
    draggedView.center = CGPoint(x: draggedView.center.x + translation.x, y: draggedView.center.y + translation.y)
    gesture.setTranslation(.zero, in: view)
}

@objc func handleTapGestured(_ gesture: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    if self.view == gesture.view{
        let loc = gesture.location(in: self.view)
        location = loc
    }
}

@objc func addQuarter(){
    
    let subview = UIImageView()
    
    subview.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    addBoxes.append(subview)
    view.addSubview(subview)
    
    let pan = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handlePanGestured(_:)))
    subview.addGestureRecognizer(pan)
 
    subview.frame = CGRect(x: view.bounds.midX , y: view.bounds.midY + CGFloat(100), width: CGFloat(100), height: 100)
    subview.backgroundColor = .brown
    
    addBoxes.append(subview)
    
}
}

extension UIView{
var copyView : UIView?{
    if let archiv = try? NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: self, requiringSecureCoding: false){
        if let view = try? NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveTopLevelObjectWithData(archiv) as? UIView{
            return view
        }
    }
    return nil
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

a way to achieve `copy`.

You can do it in the `Model` level.

In your case, to copy View, is to get the View property ( Frame Size, Color ),

then create a new one.

---

**here is the code instruction**

model part

```
// you can add info , in your needs
struct ViewModel{
     let color: UIColor
     let size: CGSize
}
```

Logic Part:

add an `UITapGestureRecognizer`  to the base view (add part view)

in copy mode, the view `isUserInteractionEnabled` false,

in add mode, the view `isUserInteractionEnabled` true,

```
var selectModel: ViewModel?


@objc func copyBox() {

    
    // now in the copy mode
}


func selectView(){
      // get current model
      selectModel = ViewModel(color: yourView.backgroundColor, size: yourView.frame.size)
}


@objc func AddBox() {

    
    // now in the add mode / paste mode
}


func touchToAdd(_ gesture: UITapGestureRecognizer){
     // get the tap location,
     // the location point is the new view's center

     //  use the model from `func selectView(){`

     //  now you got center . frame size 、color， enough to create a new one ( a copy)
}
```

Comment: I put  subview.isUserInteractionEnabled = true in add Box and it toucToAdd I put selectView but its not having any effect. I am pretty confused. Can you feel out more of the method body? Thanks.